# Strikethrough with Xcode markup

Tags: xcode, markdown, markup, swift-playground

Is there any way to use strikethrough in Xcode? I'm using two tildas (`~~ text ~~`) but it doesn't work.

[image]

When I go to Editor > Show Rendered Markup it shows without strikethrough:

[image]

Other formatting options like `#`/`_text_` and so on work fine.

Comment: I don't know anything about Xcode, but it looks like you have spaces between the tildes and text? Try `~~text~~` without any spaces. (Note that strikethrough _isn't_ part of [the original Markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), though it is a common extension. I don't know what version of Markdown Xcode uses.)

Comment: @Chris unfortunately `~~text~~` doesn't work either. I didn't know that it's not a part of the Markdown specification so it might explain this.